# Accessing method in a class from MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a WPF application for students' registration with a simple form containing Name, matriculation number, credits and so on.
I have a `Mainwindow.xaml` and a `Student.cs`.

In my `MainWindow.xaml` I have an advance button that should advance the level of the students, based on the credits (if the student has more than 120 credits, level should be advanced to "2")

This is the **Student.cs** with Advance() method

```
class Student
{
    private int matric;                            
    private int level;                  
    private int credits;                

    public Student() { }       

    public int Matric                   
    {
        get { return matric; }          
        set                            
        {
           //there should be a range check for the 
            matric = value;
        }
    }

    public int Level
    {
        get { return level; }
        set { level = value; }
    }

    public int Credits
    {
        get { return credits; }
        set { credits = value; }
    }

    //this is my problem:

    public int Advance() 
    {
        if (Credits >= 0 && Credits < 120)
        {
            return Level;
        }
        else if (credits >= 120)
        {
            return Level++;
        }
        else if (credits >= 240)
        {
            return Level++;
        }
        else if (Credits >= 360)
        {
            return Level++;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**, just the part with the button and the textboxes

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLevel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="184,266,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtCredit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="184,328,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdvance" Content="Advance" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,267,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnAdvance_Click"/>
```

And where I'm trying to call the method 
**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Student student;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        student = new Student();            
        student.Credits = int.Parse(txtCredit.Text);
        student.Level = int.Parse(txtLevel.Text);

    }

    private void btnAdvance_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        student.Advance();              //this should be the call of the method
    }
}
```

Of course it's not working...
Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**
This is what I have now, still not working

```
    public void Advance()
    {
        if (Credits >= 0 && Credits < 120)
        {
            Level = 1;
        }
        else if (credits >= 120 && Level == 1)
        {
            Level = 2;
        }
        else if (credits >= 240 && Level == 2)
        {
            Level = 3;
        }
        else if (Credits >= 360 && Level == 3)
        {
            Level = 4;
        }
        else if (Level == 4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can't advance more!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Advance is not possible!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what errors are you facing?

Comment: If you want the UI to reflect the changes in `student`, you will need to update `txtLevel` after calling `student.Advance();`.

Comment: @crashmstr is correct. You need to use the function.

Comment: In the class, the student is advanced. But to see the changes you need to get the value and reflect it in some TextBlock or TextBox or in some other way.

Comment: `txtLevel.Text = student.Level.ToString();`? This is just the reverse of what you do in `btnSet_Click` (but you should check to make sure `sudent != null` and also will need to think about when you create a `new student` as well as what happens if they keep clicking your `Advance` button).

Comment: Ok, now 'txtLevel' is updated, but, as @crashmstr said, keeping pressing 'Advance' button will advance my level forever....

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you also need to update the Advance method logic to include Level in your conditional statements:  else if (credits >= 120 && Level == 1). Otherwise, multiple Advance clicks will continue to increment the Level when it should not, without the credits being adjusted higher.

Comment: Yes @Bobby, you are right...it does even if it shouldn't...

Comment: When you say it is still not working, what do you mean? Are you getting an error? Is something not updating? What exactly are you experiencing?

Comment: I can reach level 1, but after that, with ie. credits at 125, it always show the message "Advance is not possible!" and level returns to 0 in the textbox.

Comment: I see. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should be doing this with binding, where you bind the Level textbox to the Level property of the student, implementing iNotifyPropertyChanged on your model. I would suggest you research binding and redesign it this way.

However, if you wish to proceed in your current design, here are changes I would suggest to achieve the behavior you are expecting:

1) In `btnSet_Click`, remove this line: `student.Level = int.Parse(txtLevel.Text);` Your Level should not be set by the TextBox; it should be set by the Advance method.

2) Your Advance method should look like follows:

```
public int Advance()
    {
        if (Credits >= 0 && Credits < 120)
        {
            level = 1;
        }
        else if (credits >= 120 && credits < 240)
        {
            level = 2;
        }
        else if (credits >= 240 && credits < 360)
        {
            level = 3;
        }
        else if (Credits >= 360)
        {
            if (level != 4)
            {
                level = 4;
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can't advance more!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Advance is not possible!");
        }

        return level;
    }
```

3) Add the `IsReadOnly="True"` attribute to the Level Textbox, as it should not be settable from the interface.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLevel" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="184,266,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

4) Since you are not using binding, in your Advance_click, you will need to post the returned value back to the interface:

```
private void btnAdvance_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtLevel.Text = student.Advance();              //this should be the call of the method        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to omit the set, then have btnAdvance do both. The problem is that the student in set does not exist in advance because it is a different roundtrip.

I.e. Advance have to look at the textboxes and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're updating your model item and not setting your control to the updated value afterwards.

Comment: @Koosshh56 I assume you're expecting your level textbox to display the value. I can't see anything in your code attempting to write back to text box, after updating your buisness object ( student)